# How to apply the where clause of the whole query on the sub-queries also?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery, query-optimization

I have the following SQL query :

```
SELECT users.username, users.id, count(tahminler.tahmin)as tahmins_no, m.winnings
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN tahminler ON users.id = tahminler.user_id 
LEFT JOIN matches_of_comments ON tahminler.match_id = matches_of_comments.match_id
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT user_id ,count(result) as winnings from tahminler WHERE result = 1 group by user_id) as m ON m.user_id = users.id
WHERE (MONTH( STR_TO_DATE( matches_of_comments.match_date,  '%d.%m.%Y' ) ) =  01 AND YEAR( STR_TO_DATE( matches_of_comments.match_date,  '%d.%m.%Y' ) ) =  2014 AND flag=1)
GROUP BY users.id 
having count(tahminler.tahmin) > 0
```

The Where clause did not apply on the the sub-query (m) . I do not want to add the same clause inside the sub-query it will make the query complicated and not optimized . Is there a way to apply this condition on the sub-query also without repeat it inside the sub-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to join the same table two times in your query. You can get the result from below query.

Try this:

```
SELECT u.username, u.id, COUNT(t.tahmin) AS tahmins_no, 
       SUM(t.result = 1) AS winnings
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN tahminler t ON u.id = t.user_id 
LEFT JOIN matches_of_comments mc ON t.match_id = mc.match_id
WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(mc.match_date, '%d.%m.%Y')) = 1 AND 
      YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(mc.match_date, '%d.%m.%Y')) = 2014 AND flag=1
GROUP BY u.id 
HAVING tahmins_no > 0
```

Comment: that works like charm. but Why did u use sum instead of count?

Comment: @Basel You're most welcome... You want the users whose result is 1. You can do this with `SUM(t.result = 1)` or `SUM(CASE t.result WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` both are same